# Are there Min and Max functions that work properly on Intervals?

Tags: functions

Mathematica overloads the `Min` and `Max` functions to retrieve the lower and upper bounds of an interval.

I need functions that work properly on `Interval` arguments.  For example, the minimum of `Interval[{3,4}]` and `Interval[{2,5}]` should be `Interval[{2,4}]`.

To clarify based on comments, I'm looking for the tightest possible bounds for the `Min` and `Max` functions, given the constraints of the intervals.  For example, the `Max` function of the intervals {2,3} and {7,8} will be {7,8}, because all values in the interval {7,8} are greater than any value in the interval {2,3}.

(Note:  I'm not looking for an ordering relation for intervals. The `Min` and `Max` operations often produce new intervals.  See the first example, above.)

I've written my own functions to do this, that only work for simple intervals:

```
intervalopf[a_Interval, b_Interval, op_] := 
 Flatten[Outer[op, {Min[a], Max[a]}, {Min[b], Max[b]}]]
intervalop[a_Interval, b_Interval, op_] := 
 With[{v = intervalopf[a, b, op]}, Interval[{Min[v], Max[v]}]]
```

Are there built-in functions I should be using?

And, how can I generalize this to intervals that are unions?

Comment: From your example it seems the result of min should be an interval that goes from the min of the lower bounds to the min of the upper bounds, right? How would it work with intervals such as `Interval[{min1, max1}, {min2, max2}, ...]`?

Comment: In any case, I doubt there's a built-in

Comment: @Rojo A sense-in?

Comment: Since there is probably not a built-in, why don't you rephrase the question to ask how to write the custom function?  You might get a better method than what you're using now.

Comment: @payne First you need to specify exactly, how this `Min`and `Max` on intervals should work, because the situation is similar to 2d vectors or complex numbers, where no ordering relation exist.

Comment: Thank you for the comments.  I clarified my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: A slightly shorter version.

```
minInterval[i_] := Interval[Min /@ Transpose[i[[All, 1]]]]
maxInterval[i_] := Interval[Max /@ Transpose[i[[All, 1]]]]
```

---

**Usage**

```
minInterval@{Interval[{3, 4}], Interval[{2, 5}], Interval[{2, 4}] }
maxInterval@{Interval[{3, 4}], Interval[{7, 8}] }
```

> Interval[{2, 4}]
>   Interval[{7,8}]

---

**Initial Suggestion:**

```
minInterval[intervals_]:=Interval@{Min[intervals[[All,1,1]]],Min[intervals[[All,1,2]]]}
maxInterval[intervals_]:=Interval@{Max[intervals[[All,1,1]]],Max[intervals[[All,1,2]]]}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for (for simple intervals).  I wanted to (a) make sure I wasn't missing a built-in, and (b) understand a better Mathematica-ish idiom for doing this.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you forgot to wrap the output in `Interval` in your edit version

Comment: @Rojo Yes, I did. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another solution

```
minInterval = Interval @@ MapThread[Min, List @@@ #, 2] &;

minInterval@{Interval[{1, 2}], Interval[{5, 6}], Interval[{9, 10}]}
```

> ```
> Interval[{1, 2}]
> ```

It works also for unions of intervals (if you need to find the minimum union)

```
minInterval@{Interval[{1,2}, {3,4}], Interval[{5,6}, {7,8}], Interval[{9,10}, {11,12}]}
```

> ```
> Interval[{1, 2}, {3, 4}]
> ```