# Is there an analog of the `Complement` function for intervals?

Tags: intervals

I have two intervals:

```
i1 = Interval[{1,4}];
i2 = Interval[{2,3}];
```

I need a function that subtracts `i2` from `i1`, returning:

```
Interval[{1,2},{3,4}]
```

In other words, is there an analog of the `Complement` function for intervals? And if not, how would one implement it?

Comment: On the right side of this page, you'll see a list of related questions. One of the related questions is about finding complements of intervals:?

http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11345/can-mathematica-handle-open-intervals-interval-complements?rq=1

Comment: Please note that `Interval` objects represent closed intervals. If you complement two such overlapping intervals, the result will have an interval with an open end. You can't represent that on Mathematica with a plain `Interval` object.

Comment: @Searke, I've seen that answer, but it does not seem to be very scalable. I have thousands of intervals, and it would be hard to redefine all of them as inequalities.

Comment: @kirma, In my particular application it doesn't matter whether the intervals or open or closed, if there's a way to represent the resulting set as a closed interval (even if strictly speaking it should be open), I'd love to know it.

Comment: Have you seen [Are there Min and Max functions that work properly on Intervals?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35240/are-there-min-and-max-functions-that-work-properly-on-intervals)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not bother about the endpoints, you could define a complement function in the following way:

```
complement[x_Interval] := Interval @@ Partition[Flatten[{-\[Infinity], List @@ x, \[Infinity]}], 2]


complement[Interval[{1,2}]]
(* Interval[{-\[Infinity],1},{2,\[Infinity]}]*)

complement[Interval[{1,2},{3,4}]]
(*Interval[{-\[Infinity],1},{2,3},{4,\[Infinity]}]*)
```

Subtracting can be done with `IntervalIntersection`:

```
a=Interval[{0, 10}];
b=Interval[{1,3}, {7, 12}];
IntervalIntersection[a, complement[b]]

(*Interval[{0,1},{3,7}]*)
```

Comment: Fred, this is great. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[itrF, slitrF, intervalComplementF]
slitrF = Statistics`Library`IntervalToRegion;
itrF[x_][Interval[p : {_, _} ..]] := Or @@ (slitrF[#, x] & /@ Interval /@ {p});
intervalComplementF = Interval @@ (Reduce[itrF[x]@# && Not[itrF[x]@#2], x, Reals] /. 
  { Or -> List , Inequality[a_, __, b_] :> {a, b}, 
  Less[_, a_] | LessEqual[_, a_] :> {-Infinity, a}, 
  Greater[_, b_] | GreaterEqual[_, b_] :> {b, Infinity}} ) &;
```

Examples:

```
i1 = Interval[{1, 4}];
i2 = Interval[{2, 3}]; 
intervalComplementF[i1, i2]
```

> Interval[{1, 2}, {3, 4}]

```
a = Interval[{0, 10}];
b = Interval[{1, 3}, {7, 12}];
intervalComplementF[a, b]
```

> Interval[{0, 1}, {3, 7}]

```
intervalComplementF[Interval[{-Infinity, Infinity}], Interval[{2, 3}, {5, 6}]]
```

> Interval[{-Infinity, 2}, {3, 5}, {6, Infinity}]